# Count the length of a string excluding a list of keywords?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating a number of fields based on the length of the string entered.  However, any of the values in the following array must NOT count against the string length:

```
var omittedSubStrings = ["%KEYWORD%","{Keyword:AltText}","%CITY_STATE%","%CITY%","%KEYWORD%","%KEY_WORD%","%QUERY_KEYWORD%","%QUERY_KEY_WORD%","$CLICK_ID$","$LOCATION$","%URLENC_CITY%","%NOSPACE_CITY%","%STATE%","$USER_PLACEMENT_INV_ID$"];
```

so for example if my string is:

```
var str = "Hello %CITY%";
```

I want to get the length of that string s.t it equals 6. Multiple variables can possibly be used in one string, and they must all not count against length.

Suggestions?

Comment: can those keywords be nested - as in `{Keyword:AltText$CITY$}`?

Comment: +1 to @Anurag's question

Comment: no, they won't be nested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function countSubstringless(str, subStrings) {
    var length = subStrings.length;
    for (var i=0; i<length; i+=1) {
        str = str.replace(subStrings[i], '');
    }
    return str.length;
}

var omittedSubStrings = ["%KEYWORD%","{Keyword:AltText}","%CITY_STATE%","%CITY%","%KEYWORD%","%KEY_WORD%","%QUERY_KEYWORD%","%QUERY_KEY_WORD%","$CLICK_ID$","$LOCATION$","%URLENC_CITY%","%NOSPACE_CITY%","%STATE%","$USER_PLACEMENT_INV_ID$"];
var str = "Hello %CITY%";

console.log(countSubstringless(str, omittedSubStrings));
// 6
```

Comment: While likely not an issue here, this may be problematic on `["KEY", "%KEYWORD%"]`.

Comment: @pst - I think it's reasonable to assume that the keyword will be padded by **special** characters such as `%` or `$` on either side to avoid collisions with regular text. Otherwise, the OP will need a full blown parser. @PPvG - you probably want to assign the result of calling `.replace` back to `countableStr` as it creates a new string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative answer.

Note that *this assumes that no special regular expression characters appear in the word list* (or they are otherwise properly guarded):

```
var omittedSubStrings = ["%KEYWORD%","{Keyword:AltText}","%CITY_STATE%","%CITY%","%KEYWORD%","%KEY_WORD%","%QUERY_KEYWORD%","%QUERY_KEY_WORD%","$CLICK_ID$","$LOCATION$","%URLENC_CITY%","%NOSPACE_CITY%","%STATE%","$USER_PLACEMENT_INV_ID$"]

// make regular expression alternation for all words, global search
var re = new RegExp(omittedSubStrings.join("|"), "g")

var str = "%KEYWORD%Hello %CITY%"
str.replace(re, "").length // 6
```

(The question of "is this better?" is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Happy coding.